# Error al enviar correo con PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buen día a todos.

Se me presenta el siguiente error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isSMTP()

Cuando trato de enviar un correo automático.
He revisado en muchos foros y no he podido encontrar el problema, espero me puedan ayudar.

Mi código:

```
function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){

        include "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
        include "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

        //$mail-> SMTPDebug = 2;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; //Modificado Brian 
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //Modificado Brian
        $mail->Port = 465; //Modificado

        $mail->Username = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'; //Modificado Brian
        $mail->Password = 'xxxx'; //Modificado Brian

        $mail->setFrom('xxxx@gmail', 'Sistemas de Gestion'); //Modificado
        $mail->addAddress($email, $nombre);

        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);

        if($mail->send())
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que instanciar la clase PHPMailer en un objeto `$mail` para poder usar el método `isSMTP()`.

```
function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){
    include "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // <----------- Debes agregar esta línea
    // el resto de tu código...
```

Comment: Trate como tu me dices y me sale el siguiente error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer'

Comment: y la ruta del PHPMailer esta bien colocada, osea cual es tu ruta para esa clase la que tu tienes ?

Comment: Prueba instanciando así: `$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();`. Esto puede ser necesario si la versión de PHPMailer que usas es reciente y además no usas Composer para cargarla.

Comment: @javiertapia Probé instanciando con tu ejemplo y me sale ya es otro errror, pero de la libreria te comparto la funcion: protected function smtpSend($header, $body)
    {
        $bad_rcpt = [];
        if (!$this->smtpConnect($this->SMTPOptions)) {
            throw new Exception($this->lang('smtp_connect_failed'), self::STOP_CRITICAL);
        }

Comment: @javiertapia Ya corregí el error anterior ahora se ejecuta, no envía el email pero tampoco me arroja error!

Comment: @Brian Velez - En tu código especificas los parámetros Host, Port, Username y Password. Algunos transportes SMTP (por ejemplo, Amazon SES) requieren además especificar un parámetro de seguridad como `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`. Revisa si es el caso de tu Host.

Comment: @javiertapia Ya revise todo y todos los parámetros están bien, no se que más debería revisar.

Comment: @Brian Velez - Al final, después de `$mail->Send();` y antes del `return`, agrega `echo $mail->ErrorInfo;` para ver si PHPMailer muestra algún mensaje de error. Si hay mensaje, publícalo aquí. Si no hay mensaje, el problema ya no es de PHP sino del envío por el servidor SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Este es mi configuración espero te sirva no es necesario que importes include "PHPMailer/SMTP.php"; y necesitas instanciar el PHPMAILER.

```
include "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// echo "Instaciamos PHPMailer\n";

#configuracion de envio de correos
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username   = "xxxxxxxo@xxx.com";
$mail->Password   = "xxxxxx";

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
));

$mail->setFrom('xxxxxx@xxxx.com', "EJEMPLO");  
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = utf8_decode($subject);
$mail->Body = $body;
//Definimos AltBody por si el destinatario del correo no admite email con formato html 
$mail->AltBody = $body;
$exito = $mail->Send();
```

Comment: También probe con tu configuración y me arroja el mismo error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer'  No se que estoy haciendo mal, sera la librería?

Comment: revisa si tu libreria se llama asi PHPMailer.php  porque aveces se llama class.phpmailer.php

Comment: Revisa en la ruta donde esta tu libreria y mira que nombre tiene el archivo adicional revisa si estás colocando bien la ruta en tu código veo que el .php lo tienes dentro de una carpeta PHPMailer

Comment: Les comparto la ruta: public_html/funcs/PHPMailer ->  PHPMailer.php

Comment: y tu archivo esta en la carpeta funcs? porque si lo tienes en la raiz public_html debes colocarlo así include "funcs/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";